# Import pointing to wrong directory

Tags: typescript

Tried to create alias so I can shorten my import path, but an error `Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@/src/lib/utils" from "src/artifact/story/main/kbd.ts". Does the file exist?` occurred.

I have included my app directory map, error message, location of error occurred, and my tsconfig. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SRC
│   App.css
│   App.tsx
│   index.css
│   LeftPanel.tsx
│   main.tsx
│   output.css
│   Loader.tsx
│   vite-env.d.ts
│
├───artifact
│   │   1-main.ts
│   │
│   └───story
│       ├───load
│       │       index.tsx
│       │
│       └───main
│               index.tsx
│               kbd.ts
│
├───assets
│       react.svg
│
├───lib
│       buttonDict.ts
│       dict-gen.ts
│       utils.ts
│
└───store
        interface.ts
        store.ts
```

**[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@/src/lib/utils" from "src/artifact/story/main/kbd.ts". Does the file exist?**

```
 Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: C:/dev/react-ag/src/artifact/story/main/kbd.ts:1:25
  1  |  import { resetKbd } from "@/src/lib/utils";
     |                            ^
  2  |  import { useBoundStore } from "@/src/store/store";
```

tsconfig.json

```
"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
    },
```

UPDATE 1: Changed wrong title